# how to add text on pie chart slice in CustomPaint(Canvas) widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas

[image]

I have to add text on pie chart slices in canvas circle drawing and i have 3 slices in pie chart (cash/card/bill) and i want to set that text with their percentage on pie chart particular slice

note :-  i completed drawing this chart now i only have to add text on slices

Comment: Can you include your chart-code?

Comment: chart image is included

Comment: are you using any package like `pie_chart`?

Comment: no, i drawing it on canvas

Comment: Can you include that widget? also you can try those package.

Answer (score 1):

To paint text in flutter using `CustomPainter` you need to use `TextSpan` and `TextPainter` like so:

```dart
TextSpan span = new TextSpan(style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]), text: yourText);
TextPainter tp = new TextPainter(text: span, textAlign: TextAlign.left, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr);
tp.layout();
tp.paint(canvas, new Offset(5.0, 5.0));
```

Comment: i have to add text on particular slice of pie chart

Comment: Well, then you just have to come up with some formula to calculate the right offset and plug it in the above code snippet.